# Switching tenses?

Tags: abstract, grammar

I finished writing a paper but haven't sorted out the abstract yet. Currently it looks something like this, but I'm not sure if this is OK.

> Hello, my name is _____ and I am currently a ______ in high school.
>   This is my first paper on math.
>
> In this paper, we investigate....

Notice how I changed from "I" to "we" in the second paragraph. I'm not sure if this is normal?

Comment: What paper is this? "Hello, my name is ..." would seem very strange in any scientific literature I've read.

Comment: @JiK: It's not a really serious paper, I wrote it for a journal our school math club runs

Comment: Are you asking about what you should *write* in the abstract, or what you should *say* when presenting a paper? Your first sentence would be out of place in the written paper, regardless of the I/we issue. However, when presenting a paper, it's common enough to start by introducing yourself (using "I") and then switch to "we".

Comment: @mhwombat: Ok, please advise me on what to change it to. I want to keep the part where I say that I am a high school student and this is my part paper. Thanks!

Comment: @user45220 That it's your paper and that you are a high school student should both be evident from the author and the affiliation on the title page. Mentioning it in the abstract is not needed if you want to sound professional.

Comment: is it about *tenses* or the *grammatical number*?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By usual standards of academic writing, the first paragraph should be removed entirely.  In academic writing, unlike conversations, the author does not begin by introducing herself.  The focus is always on the topic of the paper, not the person who wrote it.

This is particularly out of place in the abstract, which should be a very concise summary of the contents of the paper, so that a reader can tell as quickly as possible if the paper will be interesting or useful to him.  It definitely should not contain anything unnecessary.  (Also, it is normally limited to one paragraph.)

In some cases, a brief biography of the author can be placed at the beginning or (more commonly) the end of the paper.  But it's normally written in third person, and should take a formal, rather than conversational, tone (don't say "Hello").

> User45220 is a sophomore at Groucho Marx High School in Frostbite Falls, Minnesota.  This is her first mathematics paper.  Her interests include geometry and calculus.

The question of whether or not to include a biography, and if so where to place it, is up to the journal where you will publish; usually they have a policy of either always including biographies, or never including them.

Now let me address the question I think you really wanted to ask: within the paper, should the author be referred to as "I" or "We"?  (Grammatically, this distinction is called [number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_number), not [tense](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_tense) which is something else.)  There is no universal agreement on this.  Historically, "we" has been more common, even if there is only one author. ("In this paper, we investigate splines.") But some authors prefer to use "I" ("I investigate splines"), and this is generally okay, if the editor of the journal approves.  Another possibility is to use third person, and use "The author investigates splines" or "The authors investigate splines", according to whether you are writing the paper yourself or with co-authors.  Ultimately, your preference as to which option to use is part of your own personal writing style.

Answer (score 1):

You may choose as you wish. Personally, I find "we" in papers authored by a singular person very odd, and I find the image that the author prefers to use the majestic plural in reference to himself in ordinary life inescapable. However, it is quite common, and probably the "safe choice". Most top-tier papers are very happy with the singular first person.
Certainly I (that is to say, "we"!) would not be inconsistent. If you want to begin with "I", then continue that way. If you are going to use "we", then keep it consistent throughout your work.
Finally, do not worry too much about it. If your paper is accepted, you may ask the journal editors for their opinion.
Good luck in your submission!

Comment: In a math paper, for example, the use of "we" in a single-authored paper invites the reader directly into the process. It's not a majestic plural but rather an invitation to the reader.

Comment: Aye, it can be, no doubt of this; if the progressive or present aspects are used in the verb conjugation. But quite often it is the perfect tense "we found", which precludes the reader from joining in.